# extend a parent of a nest for grouping common parameters in SASS

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

What the best way to group common parameters for similar elements in SASS?

I'm using "@extend &" inside the nest.

It looks simpler than writing a separate @mixin.
But I'm just wondering if I should avoid to write in this way with some reasons.

For example,

HTML

```
<button class="btn-aaa">Red Button</button>
<button class="btn-bbb">Green Button</button>
```

SCSS

```
.btn { 
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  &::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 100%;
      margin-left: 20px;
  }
  &-aaa {
    @extend &;
    background-color: red;
    &::before {
      background: url("/images/aaa.svg") no-repeat center;
    }
  }
  &-bbb {
    @extend &;
    background-color: green;
    &::before {
      background: url("/images/bbb.svg") no-repeat center;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will throw the error `Can't extend &: can't extend parent selectors`

Comment: `@extend &` would be the equivalent of a selector trying to extend itself, which isn't possible.